# Some Special characters are shows up in json response from php while calling from angularjs controller

Tags: php, json, angularjs, http

```
<pre>
 $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'api/userBadgeIdRound.php',
                    data: { 'idUser': $scope.idUser },
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=iso-8859-1;' }
                })
                .success(function (data, status) {
                   //console.log(data);
                    //console.log(status);
                    //$scope.messages = JSON.stringify(data);
                    $scope.userBadges = data.badges;
                    $scope.idRound = data.round.idRound;
                })
                .error(function (data, status) {
                    console.log("post errore");
                });
</pre>
<em>
the output i am getting like this <pre>
Array�����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
������������
</pre>
instead of this
<pre>
{"badges":[{"name":"some thing","value":"some thing","image":"path"},{"name":"some thing","value":"some thing","image":"path"}],"round":{"idRound":"305"}}
</pre>

</em>
```

this is in microsoft azure webmatrix but where as in other server its running perfectly i dont know what is the problem i tried in several ways but no use can any one suggest me something and i found something related [here](http://blog.salientdigital.com/2009/06/06/special-characters-showing-up-as-a-question-mark-inside-of-a-black-diamond/) i changed my charset : UTF-8 to iso-8859-1 but no change in response

Comment: Have you checked the network tab in your developer tools/web inspector of choice?

Comment: yes i can see network tab in developers tools but i dont know  what i need to see in that @maurycy sorry i never checked it can you tell me what i have to look in it

Comment: When you make the POST request you will see it in network tab (keep it open while you do the call) then you should see response, it's probably server wrong encoding or transofrming response

Comment: Yes I Checked it like you said @maurycy i think its server wrong encoding but i am not sure because  i am getting response  for other http methods only this one making error like this so i dont know